# Retrieve dictionary items according to a list or priority keys

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I would like to retrieve dictionary keys according to a list of priority keys.
The dictionary looks like:

```
My_dic = {'name': 'John', 'age': '33', 'gender':'male', 'car': 'SUV'}
```

And the list of criteria is:

```
My_criteria = ['gender', 'age', 'car', 'name']
```

How can this be done in a pythonic way?

Comment: Python dictionaries cannot be sorted. Sorting the *display* of them is possible though. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key

Comment: I like to use [operator module functions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#operator-module-functions) for the key function.

Comment: @Jeffrey: Thanks for the quick reply. If I use OrderedDict, how would I order it by my list?

Comment: @Empario see my answer below to use an OrderedDict.

Answer (score 1):

you can retrieve elements by the order you specified

```
for k in sorted(My_dic, key=My_criteria.index):
    print(k,":",My_dic.get(k))
```

Comment: I like your approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an OrderedDict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

My_dic = {'name': 'John', 'age': '33', 'gender':'male', 'car': 'SUV'}
My_criteria = ['gender', 'age', 'car', 'name']

My_dic = OrderedDict([(x, My_dic[x]) for x in My_criteria])
# OrderedDict([('gender', 'male'),
#              ('age', '33'),
#              ('car', 'SUV'),
#              ('name', 'John')])
```

The advantage is that you can still access your data as if it was a dictionary (e.g. `My_dic['age']`).

Comment: I like your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are not sortable, due to the way the information is stored (http://www.python-course.eu/dictionaries.php).

You could create a new list of tuple values using list comprehension, like:

`ordered_info = [(i,my_dic[i]) for i in my_criteria]`

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through your priority keys, not your dict, then get values using those keys:

```
for key in My_criteria:
    print My_dic[key]
```

will print the values of your keys in the order that `My_criteria` is in.